# Are login/signup links a semantic use-case of HTML5 <menu>

Tags: html, semantic-markup

[**Live Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5833H/9/)

[`HTML5 <menu> element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element)

**HTML5:**

```
<menu type="list">
  <li><a href="/signup/"> Sign Up </a></li>
  <li><a href="/login/"> Log In </a></li>
</menu>
```

I want to add a signup / login menu to my website.

- Would using `<menu>` be semantic?
- Should I use `<ul>` instead?

**Edit:** I'm using semantic HTML5. Browser support is irrelevant.

Comment: Just an FYI: The `<menu>` tag is [not supported by any major browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_menu.asp).  While it might work, it probably isn't a good idea for a modern website.

Comment: @overzealous please [don't link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com). here's a much more [reputable site](http://caniuse.com/#search=menu) that is kept up to date.

Comment: @Jason - Will do, from now on.  That's a bad habit from searching Google!  Thanks!

Comment: @OverZealous the question was about semantics not about browser support

Comment: Hence why it was a comment - not an answer.  Carry on.

Comment: raynos, in terms of semantics you're doing it right. @overzealous was merely warning you that regardless of semantics, you probably should try something different since the tag is not supported anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm sure you're aware:

> The menu element represents a list of commands.

It really just depends on how you define "list" and "commands." Are "Login" and "Sign up"  *commands*? Or are they *list items*? Personally I think they're commands. A list (`ul` or `ol`) is more akin to something *longer*, two items just don't seem to make a list, to me. Login and Sign up seem like commands because they're what Stephen Krug, in [*Don't Make Me Think*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) calls "Utilities":

> Utilities are links to important elements of the site that aren't really part of the content hierarchy.

These are contrasted with what he calls "Sections":

> links to the main sections of the site: the top level of the site's hierarchy [navigation]

This makes sense semantically: You use `<nav>` for Krug's "sections" (navigation) and `<menu>` for utilities or commands (Log in, Sign Up, Search, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to matter too much. There are a lot of options you can choose, even the new `<nav>` tag. But an unordered list certainly isn't going to wreak havoc on your code or not pass HTML5 validation.

I still use unordered lists for my navigations. This includes websites with a top heading nav, sidebar, and footer links. But speaking in semantics, I would recommend the `nav` element over `menu`.

Comment: I already use `<nav>` for my website navigation. I think login/signup are seperate from navigation